# Facebook Marketing Api Error : (#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v3.2."

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-marketing-api

When trying to use the Facebook Marketing API I'm getting the error this

```
Response:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v3.2.",
```

How I can upgrade facebook marketing api version from v3.0 to v3.2 ?

when I went to the "API Upgrade Tool"; nothing is showing up as shown in the following picture.

[image]

I already change the api version v3.0 to v3.2 in my marketing api setting
but same error occur.

[image]

Please tell me how I can upgrade the Marketing API from v3.0 to v3.2.

Comment: Specify the API version directly in your API calls …? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/versions#calling_versioned_apis

Comment: Updated the library your application utilizes to make requests.

Comment: Thank you! Javi :) 
I solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the version in your api
For example-

- https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_

This is related to version of API we are using .Facebook has discontinued support of v3.0 and v3.1 .Currently Facebook is supporting v3.2 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

Go to  **/facebookads/apiconfig.py** and change the version you want.

```
ads_api_config = {
  'API_VERSION': 'v3.3',
  'SDK_VERSION': 'v3.3.2',
  'STRICT_MODE': False
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The current latest version for **Facebook Business SDK is v4.0**

As per documentation (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk) it shows to use version *3.1.** and gave the deprecated version error.

**Solution**:
Update the **composer.json** file to use version **4.0** and update using the composer.

$~ composer update facebook/php-business-sdk

Comment: This still applies in 2021, the latest version as of July 1st, 2021 is 11.0.0 and it fixes deprecated errors.